# How do I use this google IdToken to get the users email address using PHP?

Tags: php, android, access-token, google-signin

I have an android app that uses google sign in.

I have successfully requested and retrieved an IdToken as such...

```
  GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
      .requestEmail()
      .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.google_server_client_id))
      .build();
```

later retrieved by..

```
  GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
  if(acct != null) {
    email = acct.getEmail();
    gToken = acct.getIdToken();
  }
```

I then successfully sent this IdToken to the server.

**If possible, using PHP, how do I use this IdToken to get the users email address?**  I'm so confused between IdToken, Authorization Token, Access Token, Oauth2.  I just can't weed out the garbage to get the info I need.  I need your help!  lol.

Comment: Look at the right under "Related" section, there is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31349846/2109067) link. Is it what you asking?

Comment: @ankhzet Geeze, I think that is what I need exactly.  I'll try it out.  Thank you!

Comment: @ankhzet Nice!  It worked!  Thanks again.

Comment: *thumbs up* Glad it helped =)